# How to edit a specific line in text file using line index?

Tags: c#, indexing, text-files

Im wondering how to edit a specific line using indexes of lines in text file?
Ex. I cant use filter like certain string because some lines will repeat, but only unique thing about them are in which line index are they. Basically if I want to edit 4th line in textfile and replace it with something else, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `File.ReadAllLines()` and `File.WriteAllLines()` to simplify this:

```
int index = 10; // You index set here.
string filename = "Your filename goes here";

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
lines[index] = "New line for index";
File.WriteAllLines(filename, lines);
```

Comment: whats the starting index of textfile,  0 or 1?

Comment: 0 in `C#` but if you have multiple lines with the same string, what is the key to index the one line you want?

Comment: Just to make things more clear, ill give you ex. how it works.... For each employee I save 1,2,3 or 4 in one line, and employee id is directly connected to index of a line in textfile, so employee id=3, that means he has to have line 3 in textfile. Value that I save there is either 1,2,3 or 4 and Im changing that depending on some actions that happend.